# Wordpress : development on Child theme causes two css requests from browser

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to work on a website powered by wordpress. As suggested by Wordpress community, I should be creating a child theme and need to write code on it. So, there would be two css files, one css file would be of parent theme and other would be of child theme. So, when an end-user will request, will there be two css files requests ?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please step first to [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then visit [GET started](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252149/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-stack-overflow), and finally, read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You might also consider using the dedicated [SE wordpress community](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your theme name is Theme-x

create a folder with name theme-x-child

inside the folder create  Three files

```
1. functions.php 

<?php
//
// Recommended way to include parent theme styles.
//  (Please see http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#How_to_Create_a_Child_Theme)
//  
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array('parent-style')
    );
}
//
// Your code goes below
//

2. rtl.php

/*
Theme Name:     Theme-x Child
Template:       

Right to Left text support.
*/
@import url("../Theme-x/rtl.css");

3.style

/*
Theme Name:     Theme-x Child
Description:    wordpress
Author:         admin
Template:       Theme-x Child

(optional values you can add: Theme URI, Author URI, Version, License, License URI, Tags, Text Domain)
*/
```

That's it if you want you can add the screenshot.png too. it will get the styles from your parent theme.